# Can cell phones be reprogrammed for peer-to-peer connectivity avoiding carrier base stations to create a free meshed network?

Tags: wireless, cellphone, network

In light of recent events concerning the freedom of internet, thoughts are going in the direction of breaking free from the control of wired internet service providers. One widely discussed option is WiFi router based network, but its range is quite limited. Cell phones have a much greater range though, and *everybody* has one.

Legalities aside (laws can be changed, after all) is it possible to reprogram existing cell phones mobile network modules to ultimately create a wireless internet on the mobile frequencies? Or is there a fundamental component missing for two-way communication between two cell phones?

Comment: Duplicate, but on mobile, and can't easily search for the previous question. Answer, no.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane to clarify, is your linked answer saying that a cell phone needs a receiver for the same frequency it transmits on (in addition to reprogramming) for peer-to-peer connectivity?

Comment: @user1306322 both that, and the entire protocol would need re-writing. It's not like a full/half dupex analogue system..

Comment: I see there's mentions of device-to-device communication in the design of 5G mobile network protocol (at least that's what [wikipedia page says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5G)). I'd really like to know more about that, but I guess that's a different, more specific question.

Comment: The Motorola IDEN protocol/hardware provided that. Cellphones are just radio circuitry plus a huge pile of software. If you know the hooks into the radio (probably SPI packets to configure), you can do what you want. Legal?

Comment: It can... Look up push to talk

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I'm asking about using only the phones that are already owned by people all over the world without external equipment. From a cursory search it seems like a completely separate type of mobile comms device and not something everybody owns.

Comment: @JonRB see my reply to analogsystemsrf